# Eclipse listener to detect whenever a new view has been opened?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, view, listener

I need to write Eclipse plugin code that hooks into an existing plugin's view, but I do not have that plugin's source code. I need a way to detect when an instance of this view is started, so I may find it in my memory and do my magic. Is there a way to hook into the Eclipse platform and setup an event based listener of some sort?  I could setup a background thread (started in `IStartup.earlyStartup()`) and poll for the view at a fixed interval, but I don't want to do that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IPartListener`

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

IPartService partService = window.getPartService();

partService.addPartListener(listener);
```

The listener is told about all changes to the state of parts (Views and Editors).

Comment: not sure if the answer is right or wrong. But both the question and answer are interesting :D

Comment: I thought about this, and erroneously assumed that `getPartService()` would return a part service for the workbench window it came from alone.  I did not realize it gave me a part service for the entire platform.  It worked!  Thanks!  Do I need to implement all the overridden methods, or just the ones I require?

Comment: It is an interface so you have to implement them all, but they don't have to actually do anything

Comment: Hi @greg-449. I'm using the perspectiveChanged method from this interface just fine on Eclipse 3.8, to monitor when new views are opened on my application, tracking all new views on the perspective. But, when i'm running this application on Eclipse 2023-06, the perspectiveChanged with the "changeId" equals to WorkbenchPage.CHANGE_VIEW_SHOW is been called on the application startup. With this, the loaded views, that were alread on the perspective, are been detected as new views. Was this behaveour change expected?

Comment: @JoseRenato Eclipse internals were completely rewritten for Eclipse 4 so things like this may have changed - but that was 12 years ago and I don't remember any details.